# Disable SplitViewController only on iPhone - Swift

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller, ios-universal-app

I'm working on an universal iOS app and I'm using SplitViewController. I have been trying to disable the splitView on iPhone 6+ and 6s+ in landscape mode but nothing seems to work. I attempted to override the UITraitCollection by setting its horizontalSizeClass to Compact, it doesn't seem to work either. Has anyone attempted this? Below is my code to override UITraitCollection

```
    override func overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController(childViewController: UIViewController) -> UITraitCollection? {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        let collections = [UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .Compact), UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .Compact) ]
        return UITraitCollection(traitsFromCollections: collections)
    }else {
        return super.traitCollection
    }
}
```

I have this in my viewDidLoad of the splitViewController.

Comment: Check this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/collapsed

Comment: what you mean by disable?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent splitViews from appearing on iPhones. Like how it happens to smaller iPhones like 6 and 5. I'm trying to show only the masterView on landscape orientation on bigger iPhones.